# Importing grammar from Stanford or Berkeley Parser to NLTK

Tags: python, parsing, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am looking to use a trained PCFG grammar in Python and was thinking of importing the grammar generated by either Stanford or Berkeley Parser to NLTK in pcfg format. Is there already a solution to do this available? Or a imported grammar available in pcfg format?

Are there other corpus based (relatively large) pcfg grammar available for NLTK?

Or, is there a better way to access pretrained PCFG grammar in Python?

Comment: What use do you plan to make of this "trained PCFG grammar"? It's impossible to make sense of your question without this information (perhaps even with it).

Comment: I am planning to use the pcfg grammar for my thesis work which does a variant of Inside-Outside probability calculation.